# WordPress Active Directory Plugin - Can't Recognize Groups

Tags: wordpress, active-directory

I've installed WordPress 3.9 on a Linux server and installed/activated the Active Directory Integration plugin.

I am able to pull users from the AD Server, but when I try to authorize by group I keep getting the same error message: [WARN] Authorization by group failed. User is not authorized.  It's as if the plugin can't recognize any of the groups on the AD server.

Granted the plugin was created back in 2011, and has shown very little up-keep since then, but I'm hoping someone a bit more familiar with LDAP and Active Directory will be able to offer some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had difficulty working with the [Active Directory Integration plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/active-directory-integration/). In my case I needed to modify the way the plugin selected the user from LDAP because, even though it would sign in, it wouldn't be able to authenticate based on groups.

I've posted a modified version of the plugin so you can see what I changed [link to the files.](https://github.com/chrisdobler/wordpress-active-directory-integration)

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly!  I was actually able to use the files you provided and I am now able to add users from specific AD groups and apply a designated WordPress user role.